# React Native with Agora using react-native-agora builds successfully but fails on application launch

Tags: android, react-native, agora

I have an React Native application and I am trying to integrate Agora SDK using react-native-agora. I am following the instruction given which are fairly straightforward. App builds successfully, when I run react-native run-android. However when I launch the app, it throws an exception saying.

```
Error: The package 'react-native-agora' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure: 

- You rebuilt the app after installing the package
- You are not using Expo Go
, js engine: hermes
```

react-native: v0.67.3
react-native-agora: v4.2.0